# Angular in node communication to python backend inside docker failed

Tags: python, angular, amazon-web-services, docker

I have an angular application hosted using Node and also have a python flask backend for other python operation. As these are 2 separate modules, I had created separate docker images for node+angular and python flask. In order for isolation, I also used a docker network for these containers.

I have built the images and I started the containers using these commands:

```
docker container run -d -p 5000:5000 --network reporter-net --name backend backend-server
docker container run -d -p 3000:3000 --network reporter-net --name frontend frontend-server
```

But from the frontend, I have been calling the backend using th url

```
http://backend:5000
```

mainly because I thought the communication happens from node container to this python backend. I also tried calling python backend using this url http://backend:5000 and it worked without any issue.

After deployed this architecture, it can't communicate with the backend. Later I understood from colleagues that, while running the angular code will be downloaded to browser and then the browser is directly calling the python backend.

In that case, obviously, the browser can't identify http://backend:5000. When I tried replacing it with http://localhost:5000, it worked (both on a single machine).

But how can I solve this issue while running in production? Because in production the python container may be on different servers as in microservices. So it may be difficult to get the server ip of python backend and also it is needed before building the image also.

Is there any other simple solution to this? Am I overthinking? And I am also thinking of using a ALB infront of backend servers (on production), so that we can build the frontend images using http://:5000 and it will redirect the request to any http://backend:5000.

Looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan on running your Python containers on multiple servers at once for scaling then your best option is ALB.

If you plan to have only one instance of the container running per single EC2 instance then you can use both ALB and CLB. But if you plan to run multiple instances of those containers on a single EC2 instance then you will need dynamic port mapping functionality which is part of ECS service so that your ALB (CLB will not be an option in this case) can discover your containers' ports withing its target group (as you can't hardcode them). And even if you are not going to run multiple copies of the same container on the same EC2 instance, I would still suggest using ECS service as it solves a lot of stuff for you.

Then you can use your load balancer's public DNS name as an endpoint to call from your Angular application without any issues.

I wouldn't rely on managing connectivity via IPs. Even if you already have running EC2 instances and you retrieved their IPs, if any of those instances is stopped and started, its public IP is released and you will get a new one on start. You might use Elastic IP here but that is another thing that you will need to care about. And this gets even worse when we are talking about containerization, or more precisely, running multiple copies of the same container on a single virtual host.

Comment: Actually, I need to provide backend IP inside Angular app. So, you suggest hosting the backend server via ECS+ALB first and get the ALB IP. Then give that IP to Angular app. I'm planning to host angular node server using ECS also. In that case, would it need 2 ECS clustes? One for Angular and other for Python Flask?

Comment: No, you only need two target groups, one for Python containers and one for Angular containers, and do the appropriate routing on you ALB based on listener ports (let's say Angular on port 80 and Python on port 5000). But you can use the same Cluster, the same ALB and even launch them on the same EC2 instance. But you need 2 different task definitions, one for each containerized app (one per target group).